# Symfony 5 embed form not persist foreign key

Tags: php, forms, embed, symfony5

i start to study symfony and try to make a relation between two entities with an embed form, i can persist the news information inside my entity but the foreign key is not persisted.
i try to search everywhere before disturbing and i hope somebody can help me.
 Thanks in advance.

WorkEntity.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=WorkEntityRepository::class)
 */
class WorkEntity
{
/** other attribut**/

 /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Address::class, mappedBy="workEntity",cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $address;

 /**
     * WorkEntity constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    
        $this->address = new ArrayCollection();
    }
 /**
     * @return Collection|Address[]
     */
    public function getAddress(): Collection
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    /**
     * @param Address $address
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addAddress(Address $address): self
    {
        if (!$this->address->contains($address)) {
            $this->address[] = $address;
            $address->setWorkEntity($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param Address $address
     * @return $this
     */
    public function removeAddress(Address $address): self
    {
        if ($this->address->removeElement($address)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($address->getWorkEntity() === $this) {
                $address->setWorkEntity(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

WorkEntityController.php

```
/**
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="work_entity_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
     * @param Request $request
     * @param WorkEntity $workEntity
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, WorkEntity $workEntity): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(WorkEntityType::class, $workEntity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
            $this->addFlash('success', 'Modifié avec succès');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('work_entity_index');
        }

        return $this->render('admin/work_entity/edit.html.twig', [
            'work_entity' => $workEntity,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'current_menu' => 'work_entity',
            'current_section' => 'administrative'
        ]);
    }
```

WorkEntityType.php

```
class WorkEntityType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
/**other type**/

  ->add('address', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => AddressType::class,
                'label' => 'Adresse de la société',
                'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
//                'by_reference' => false,

            ])
}
```

When i use by reference i got an issue like don't find the attributes for relying my address to workEntity.
 Error with reference => (Could not determine access type for property "address" in class "App\Entity\WorkEntity".)

Without by_reference i can persist the entity inside address but not the foreign key.
if you know what i can did for add the fereign key inside my address, i thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i find the solution after many tries my error come from the plurality of my attribute address in WorkEntity i write this singular.

```
/**
 * @return Collection|Address[]
 */
public function getAddresses(): Collection
{
return $this->addresses;
}

/**
 * @param Address $address
* @return $this
 */
public function addAddress(Address $address): self
{
if (!$this->addresses->contains($address)) {
$this->addresses[] = $address;
$address->setWorkEntity($this);
}


return $this;
}

/**
 * @param Address $address
* @return $this
 */
public function removeAddress(Address $address): self
{
if ($this->addresses->removeElement($address)) {
// set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
if ($address->getWorkEntity() === $this) {
$address->setWorkEntity(null);
}
 }

return $this;
}

Without forget my entity (inversedBy) Address.php
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=WorkEntity::class, inversedBy="addresses")
 */
private $workEntity;
```

After that i uncomment by_reference in my type WorkEntityType and now when i add an address in my work entity the following foreign key is saved in my entity "Address"